# AJAX request working, but no data inserted in to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, database

I tried to insert data into database by using ajax and php. However, I have no idea why it is not working. I have tested the html file, all the itemName, category, price are valid and the php file return me "success" just the data inserted to database is empty.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var url = "http://domain/addProduct.php?callback=?";

  $("#addProduct").click(function() {
    var itemName = $("#itemName").val();
    var category = $("#select_category").val();
    var price = $("#price").val();
    var dataString = "$itemName=" + itemName + "&category=" + category + "&price=" + price + "&addProduct=";

    if ($.trim(itemName).length > 0 & $.trim(category).length > 0 & $.trim(price).length > 0) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: dataString,
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() { 
          $("#addProduct").val('Connecting...');
        },
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          if (data == "success") {
            alert("Successfully add item");
          } else if(data="failed") {
            alert("Something Went wrong");
          }
        }
      });
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```php
<?php
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

  require("config.inc.php");

  $name = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['itemName'])));
  $category = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['category'])));
  $price = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['price'])));
  $date = date("d-m-y h:i:s");

  $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO product(name, category, price, date) VALUES(:name, :category, :price, :date)");
  $statement->execute(array(
    "name" => $name,
    "category" => $category,
    "price" => $price,
    "date"=>$date
  ));

  if($statement)
  {
    echo "success";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "failed";
  }
?>
```

Comment: are your getting any error?

Comment: You don't need to escape the variables if you're using a prepared statement. And you can't use `mysql_XXX` functions when you're using PDO.

Comment: There's also no reason to use `htmlspecialchars()` when inserting into the DB. That should only be used when displaying on a web page, to prevent XSS.

Comment: no need this 

mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['itemName'])));

use 
trim($_POST['itemName']);

Comment: and check your database date field
$date=date("d-m-y h:i:s"); you use this format

Comment: `if($statement)` is not the way to tell if the query was successful. You need to assign the result of `$statsement->execute()` to a variable, and test that.

Comment: How you fetch the $_POST data in your php.file?I mean something like if(isset($_POST['data'])

Comment: If you want to store the current time into the database, use the MySQL function `NOW()` instead of passing it from PHP.

Comment: I replace "$itemName=" in data string to "itemName=" then work but I dont know why

Comment: I know why already, because I using $_POST['itemname']; in my php file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this code:

```
dataString="$itemName="+itemName+"&category="+category+"&price="+price+"&addProduct=";
```

to:

```
dataString="itemName="+itemName+"&category="+category+"&price="+price+"&addProduct=";
```

and replace this code too:

```
if($.trim(itemName).length>0 & $.trim(category).length>0 & $.trim(price).length>0)
```

to:

```
if($.trim(itemName).length>0 && $.trim(category).length>0 && $.trim(price).length>0)
```

**Because & is a Bitwise Operator But && is Logical Operator, So in this condition we always use logical operator.**

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `date` as your table column. `date` is a predefined/reserved keyword. Change the name of your date column into your database and modify your `sql query` and try again.

Comment: actually my date format is string currently, so it is working now,the solution is replace "$itemName=" in data string to "itemName=" but I dont know why

Comment: Because you are getting your the `itemname` in your php file by using `$_POST['itemname'];` and  in your ajax request you declare `$itemname`.

Comment: ok,thanks but for the "&addProduct=" in the data string, is it necessary also? I am not familiar with this

Comment: `$` and `&` are two different things. When you submit a form or using query string to get the data, here is a way to organize variables and its value in a format which looks like `itemName=abc&category=xyz&price=123.45&addProduct=`.

Comment: yah, I know but is it compulsory to put addProduct= ?

Comment: If you are using it somewhere in your php file then my answer is `Yes`. otherwise not. and it seems that you are not using `addProduct` anywhere in your code.